# Is there an online storage service that works with Windows 7 Backup and Restore?

Tags: online-storage, windows-7-backup

I love Windows 7 Backup and Restore.. However, I kind of find it inconvenient to use external hard drive, plug it in, take it out, put it away safely etc..

1. Is there an online storage service to which Windows Backup can save the backup files to?
2. Can I make Windows Backup store the backed up data to an online storage service?

I do not want to manually upload the backup files. I want it to save directly to the cloud. Doesn't matter if the service costs me some $$$.

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit edition.

Answer (score 1):

Been trying to do this myself for a while now,  especially since microsoft backups use RAW Apis and are able to zip encrypted ntsf files (important and most secure for online backups), The way I've do it:

**First a simbolic link to Windows backup and restore:**

1. Control Panel / “Backup and Restore”
2. Click on “Set up Backup”
3. Click on “Save on Network” (even though you are not going to the network)
4. At this point you need to Run “Windows Explorer” and select the drive you are going to Backup too,
   say the C: drive.  Now make a folder to hold the Backup file (for instance MyBackups). Now right
   click on MyBackups and select the “Sharing” tab. Click on button “Share..”.  Type in the names of the
   people you want configure/run “Backup and Restore” (Administrators, etc.) and set permission level. 
   Click “Share” button and close out “Windows Explorer”.
5. Type in the network location as in\MyPcName\MyBackups and enter your login name and password.
   [Note: You can click on “Browse” then “Network” then “MyPC “name and the folder “MyBackups”.]
6. Click on “OK” and then on “Next”. I recommend you select the Folders you want backed up rather
   than letting windows choose for you. Click on “Next” and expand “Computer” and check the folders
   to backup.  (make sure you Uncheck the box “Include a system image of drives…).
7. Click “Next” and check the summary. Click on Schedule and make your choices.
8. Now click “Save settings and run backup”. You are FINISHED.

Now, this can be for example a mapped folder to any online backup service, like the dropbox folder or jungledisk, you can map and FTP folder with a local folder if you want with any software.

Remember, microsoft backups are "incremental" not "differential". deleted files are not deleted on the backups, and modified files are copy pasted maintaining the old version, not a good thing for online backups.